# How to retrieve thumbnail and image filepath with just one query in Android

Tags: android, image, cursor, thumbnails, android-contentresolver

I would like to retrieve the file path to the images and thumbnails with just one query. The code below retrieves the file paths for the thumbnails:

```
        final String [] mProjection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA};
        Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                mProjection,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        ArrayList<String> thumbFilePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        int thumbColumnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
        Uri thumbUri;

        while(imageCursor.moveToNext()) {
            thumbUri = Uri.parse(imageCursor.getString(thumbColumnIndex));

            thumbFilePaths.add(thumbUri.getPath());
        }
        imageCursor.close();
```

I can change the code to retrieve the file paths to the image, but I am not sure how to change it so that both image and thumbnail paths are retrieved for all the images.

If that's not possible, then instead of converting thumb file paths to image file paths, as has already been addressed on stackoverflow, but doesn't seem very efficient if I have to do this for many paths, can I just perform two queries - one for images and one for thumbs, and will the order of paths returned by both queries be the same? i.e. Nth path returned by both queries correspond to image and thumbnail paths for image N.

Also, I just noticed, that almost all of the thumbnail paths are retrieved multiple times, if someone can point out what's wrong with the code, I would be grateful :)

Thank You,
Gary